# How do you use Redux useDispatch to pass in values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

How do I set up actions in a `@reduxjs/toolkit` slice to pass data through the action?

Here is the slice:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export tempSlice = createSlice({
  name: "temp",
  initialState: {
    value: 1
  },
  reducers: {
    updateTemp: (data) => {
      console.log(data)
    }
  }
})

export const { updateTemp } = tempSlice.actions

export default tempSlice.reducer
```

In a react component, this doesn't work.  I keep getting errors saying it's expecting 0 arguments.

```
useDispatch(updateTemp(newData))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actions created via a state slice accept a single argument object that will be placed on the action's `payload` property. The reducer function takes two arguments, the previous `state` and the dispatched action object. `useDispatch` is a React hook and ***doesn't*** take any arguments, it returns the `dispatch` function that is used to dispatch actions.

```
export tempSlice = createSlice({
  name: "temp",
  initialState: {
    value: 1
  },
  reducers: {
    updateTemp: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action.payload);
      ...
    }
  }
})
```

```
const dispatch = useDispatch(); // <-- no arguments
...
dispatch(updateTemp(newData));  // <-- newData is action payload
```